# How to auto resize width of Vertical UIStackView when one of the view is hidden?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I have a Vertical UIStackView(S1) with UIView (V1) and UILabel(L1). UIView contains Horizontal StackView(S2) with an ImageView and Vertical StackViews(S3) to show label one below the other.

Now when I hide top view i.e V1, then my Label occupied full height which is expected. But I want stack view to compress to show only Label(L1) content. But in my case it is not reducing the width.

Here are my ViewTree and Snapshots when launched and when V1 is hidden.

[image: ViewTree/ViewLayout]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set `.isHidden = true` on a stack view's arranged subview, the stack view will remove the space it was taking up... but only in the `.axis` direction.

So your Stack View still allocates the width of `Top PINK View`.

To remove the height ***and*** width of `Top PINK View`, you'll need to remove it from the stack view... not just hide it.

Try it like this - tapping the button will toggle between hidden and showing:

```
@IBOutlet var mainStackView: UIStackView!

@IBAction func showHide(_ sender: Any) {
    if !topPINKView.isHidden {
        topPINKView.isHidden = true
        topPINKView.removeFromSuperview()
    } else {
        mainStackView.insertArrangedSubview(topPINKView, at: 0)
        topPINKView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Note: be sure to connect your stack view to the `@IBOutlet var mainStackView: UIStackView!`

---

**Edit**

You could even reduce that to:

```
@IBAction func showHide(_ sender: Any) {
    if topPINKView.superview != nil {
        topPINKView.removeFromSuperview()
    } else {
        mainStackView.insertArrangedSubview(topPINKView, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does removing of my topView and re-adding it based on some condition is ok in UITableViewCell. Do you think it can cause some performance issue?

Comment: *"Do you think it can cause some performance issue?"* -- unlikely... In fact removing it / inserting it may even provide a (very, very) slight performance gain.